# tmux doesn't display pane names

Tags: tmux

I have configured `tmux` (version `3.1c`) to display pane names in `.tmux.conf`:

```
set -g pane-border-format "#{pane_index} #{pane_title}"
set -g pane-border-status bottom
```

However, `tmux` doesn't display the pane name (neither inside macOS terminal app nor iTerm).

Comment: have you sourced your config file with `tmux source-file /path/to/.tmux.conf` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your configuration looks good, you just need to source the new configuration file with `tmux source-file /path/to/.tmux.conf`